# Malformed JSON string, encoding issue?

Tags: json, perl

I am requesting a web service and getting a JSON data as shown below. However, I keep getting the following error:

> malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "\x{feff}\x{feff}{"ur...") at /usr/share/perl5/JSON/Any.pm

http request:

```
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 10:41:03 GMT
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 10:41:03 GMT
Client-Peer: 127.0.1.1:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

json data:

`{"url":"http:\/\/example.com\/service\/rest.htm?req_data=<auth_req><request_token>20130416f186a9c0480e2501e73d19dbcd79d354<\/request_token> <\/auth_req>&user=208860&service=auth.execute&sid=0001&format=xml&v=2.0&  sign=pn9xjQjzTgQuAMarLDtiZCMaGZm4bSo8aUTGtkSt1GrxPGtK29oIL1DgHveVMwf2n7rxLHzyWrNd%2BYU6%2BxZCzs56JkMtxQMPxEJ%2Bu9Eqk5SRL6EAjWMeKheix5frPyHi0hQ4nnbiVm%2Bx3bF0KFq3cORvVCeq8wBoZU1HQXD%2BuuY%3D"}`

I suspect some kind of encoding issue because the JSON string validates fine in jslint JSON validator. But I don't know what else to look for. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Can you show the script that's generating the error?

Answer (score 2):

\x{feff} is a BOM (Byte Order Mark). I am not sure whether it is allowed at the beginning of a JSON, but it definitely should not be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to choroba for prompting me to look for the BOM. Greped 3rd party library files which generates the `url` and surely found the BOM in them.

1. `grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' .`  # Got BOM?
2. `perl -pi -nle 's/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' *.lib`  # remove them!

cheers.